# Replace the Nth occurrence of char in a string with a new substring

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to do a `str_replace()` but only at the Nth occurrence.

Inputs:

```
$originalString = "Hello world, what do you think of today's weather"; 
$findString = ' ';
$nthOccurrence = 8;
$newWord = ' beautiful ';
```

Desired Output:

```
Hello world, what do you think of today's beautiful weather
```

Comment: Related: [How can I split a string in PHP at the nth occurrence of a needle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5956066/2943403) and [Truncate string after certain number of occurrences of a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14428801/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tight little regex with `\K` that allows you to replace the nth occurrence of a string without repeating the needle in the pattern.  If your search string is dynamic and might contain characters with special meaning, then `preg_quote()` is essential to the integrity of the pattern.

If you wanted to statically write the search string and nth occurrence into your pattern, it could be:

- `(?:.*?\K ){8}`
- or more efficiently for this particular case: `(?:[^ ]*\K ){8}`

`\K` tells the regex pattern to "forget" any previously matched characters in the fullstring match. In other words, "restart the fullstring match" or "**K**eep from here".  In this case, the pattern only keeps the 8th space character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3Sukq))

```
function replaceNth(string $input, string $find, string $replacement, int $nth = 1): string {
    $pattern = '/(?:.*?\K' . preg_quote($find, '/') . '){' . $nth . '}/';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input, 1);
}

echo replaceNth($originalString, $findString, $newWord, $nthOccurrence);
// Hello world, what do you think of today's beautiful weather
```

---

Another perspective on how to grapple the asked question is: "How to insert a new string after the nth instance of a search string?"  Here is a non-regex approach that limits the explosions, prepends the new string to the last element then re-joins the elements. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DOu9K))

```
$originalString = "Hello world, what do you think of today's weather"; 
$findString = ' ';
$nthOccurrence = 8;
$newWord = 'beautiful ';   // notice that leading space was removed

function insertAfterNth($input, $find, $newString, $nth = 1) {
    $parts = explode($find, $input, $nth + 1);
    $parts[$nth] = $newString . $parts[$nth];
    return implode($find, $parts);
}

echo insertAfterNth($originalString, $findString, $newWord, $nthOccurrence);
// Hello world, what do you think of today's beautiful weather
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here - https://gist.github.com/VijayaSankarN/0d180a09130424f3af97b17d276b72bd

```
$subject = "Hello world, what do you think of today's weather"; 
$search = ' ';
$occurrence = 8;
$replace = ' nasty ';

/**
 * String replace nth occurrence
 * 
 * @param type $search      Search string
 * @param type $replace     Replace string
 * @param type $subject     Source string
 * @param type $occurrence  Nth occurrence
 * @return type         Replaced string
 */
function str_replace_n($search, $replace, $subject, $occurrence)
{

    $search = preg_quote($search);
    echo preg_replace("/^((?:(?:.*?$search){".--$occurrence."}.*?))$search/", "$1$replace", $subject);
}

str_replace_n($search, $replace, $subject, $occurrence);
```

Comment: `preg_quote()` has a `null` default delimiter. You should declare `/` as your pattern delimiter.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalString = "Hello world, what do you think of today's weather"; 
$findString = ' ';
$nthOccurrence = 8;
$newWord = ' beautiful ';

$array = str_split($originalString);
$count = 0;
$num = 0;
foreach ($array as $char) {
    if($findString == $char){
        $count++;
    }
    $num++;
    if($count == $nthOccurrence){
        array_splice( $array, $num, 0, $newWord );
        break;
    }
}
$newString = '';
foreach ($array as $char) {
    $newString .= $char;
}

echo $newString;
```

Comment: This solution has performance issues. If the string is very large, `str_split` on it will form very large array which isn't optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider something like:

```
function replaceNth($string, $substring, $replacement, $nth = 1){
  $a = explode($substring, $string); $n = $nth-1;
  for($i=0,$l=count($a)-1; $i<$l; $i++){
    $a[$i] .= $i === $n ? $replacement : $substring;
  }
  return join('', $a);
}
$originalString = 'Hello world, what do you think of today\'s weather';
$test = replaceNth($originalString, ' ', ' beautiful ' , 8);
$test2 = replaceNth($originalString, 'today\'s', 'good');
```

Answer (score 0):

First explode a string by parts, then concatenate the parts together and with search string, but at specific number concatenate with replace string (numbers here start from 0 for convenience):

```
function str_replace_nth($search, $replace, $subject, $number = 0) {
    $parts = explode($search, $subject);
    $lastPartKey = array_key_last($parts);
    $result = '';
    foreach($parts as $key => $part) {
        $result .= $part;
        if($key != $lastPartKey) {
            if($key == $number) {
                $result .= $replace;
            } else {
                $result .= $search;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$originalString = "Hello world, what do you think of today's weather"; 
$findString = ' ';
$nthOccurrence = 7;
$newWord = ' beautiful ';
$result = str_replace_nth($findString, $newWord, $originalString, $nthOccurrence);
```

Comment: If the `count()` of `$parts` never changes in ypur script, why do you keep calling `count()` and performing subtraction on every iteration? Do you actually want `array_key_last()`?  Did you consider limiting the explosions?

Comment: @mickmackusa, yes, I actually want `array_key_last()`. Thank you for the improvement!

Comment: ...but `array_key_last()`'s value never changes -- so it should be cached before looping.

Comment: I see. So `array_key_last()` function is being called a lot of time which negatively affects performance. I've improved it. Hope that the new variant is better.